# Image Stretching in responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having an image in different size. All having huge size images. I need to show the image without any stretch inside a container. That container had some height. So I have show the image to fit inside the container without any stretch. I need to use image in html not as background image. Here is my code

```css
.image-container {
  height: 420px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  height: 310px;
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
  height: 275px;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  height: 240px;
}

.image-container img {
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/under-the-tree-picture-id480585809" />
</div>
```

When I use above code image is stretching. Is there any way to fix this? Please suggest any solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Only have either max width or max height - this IS a FAQ, search for it

Comment: I dont understand why you have to reinvent the wheel when there are loads of third party css libraries like bootstrap which can do this for you? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/

Comment: Also you missed to close the `.image-container` div bracket i.e `}`

Answer (score 2):

Always reset the margins and paddings of all elements first.

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

If height or width is auto it will not stretch / mutate the original image.

```
.img-container {
    width: 420px;    // your width
}

.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Remove the media queries. Your syntax is incorrect the correct syntax for using them is :

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .img-container {
      // some changes in the class props
   }
   .another-class-change-for-480px-max-width-of-screen {

   }
}
```

Comment: I am always setting img-container width as 100%, but i am changing the height based on the device.

Comment: you must not set height of anything no matter what. just set the width. and height auto. 

Media queries should affect the width of something not height

Answer (score 0):

use `max-width` instead of `width` in your css to avoid stretching

```
.img-container img{ max-width:100%; height:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest solution for this is using `object-fit` for `IMG`.

**Note:** Not supported in IE11. [Check support here](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit).

Both images are same. Second image has `object-fit: cover`

```css
.fitImage {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/200/300.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/200/300.jpg" alt="" class="fitImage">
```

**Using jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fitImage").each(function(index) {
    var imageUrl = $(this).find('img').prop("src");
    $(this).css('background-image', "url(" + imageUrl + ")")
  });
});
```

```css
.fitImage {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.fitImage img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fitImage">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/292/200/300.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```